Multiple import impossible: Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: entity_id
This error occurs when importing multiple with version 5.74.4 but not with version 5.70.2
Indeed, in the temporary import table, the entity_id field remains empty
I did not test with other versions but I returned to backup 5.70.2 and I was able to import the data and the entity_id field is filled in.

Do you mean Multi-record custom fields?

Yes, you're right. It's when I click on Contacts -> Import Custom Data. Then I select Multi-value Custom Data. At the last step, I found the same error for the whole datas : Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: entity_id

If you can replicate the problem on one of the demo sites with a v simple set up then you (or I) could report it as a Regression

I can't replicate this on DMaster. I set up multi-record fields. Imported data from a sheet with no problems

My fields were set up for Contact Type = Individual and I had a text and a Y/N field.
My fields looked like this

My data looked like this

My import screen looked like this

If you can put more steps in your Question, or better still, replicte on dmaster.

I replicate on dmaster: I recreate all ma fields and I test with the same anonymized datas and error is the same for all (not) imported datas.

I tried with the same data as you, but I cannot import. I tried with commas and no commas in the field name, always the same error and no imported data. I create same fields as you and pd test and always same error?!?? How did you  do it??

Thank you very much for your answer. Here is the result of replication on demo website:

And same result as I described:

[EDIT] Here is the fields' definitions :


i only just got notified of your reply. i don't see the fields on Dmaster so can't comment. can you confirm it works with the simplest possible data, as i did. and if it does, then perhaps add more info to your Question as to the data that is causing the issue, types of fields, etc

Everything is gone. How to keep the personalized fields created on the demo?

I edit to add print screen of fields' definitions

demo sites are rebuilt every 24 hours

i suggest you try each of those field types separately to try and work out if it is one specific field type that is causing the issue

I follow your suggestion and second try was to import only external ID : same error and Row Imported to Contact ID is always empty. I think this bug is not a problem about a specific field.

can you send me the simplest possible csv - ie just one field, and one row of data - assuming the same will replicate on dmaster, and i will try it. wondering if it has anything to do with what is being used to create the csv. I usually work in google.sheets or libre office.

thank you very much. Here is a test file: https://www.artisan-du-web.ch/fichier_texte_pour_reproduction_bug.csv I also use LibreOffice. The only difference with your test is the first choice: I choose Contact (and not Individual) but i just tested and i still have the same error.

seems like to much to set up at my end. can you do it with a single field that takes multiple values, and give a spreadsheet which then adds two rows for the same contact. eg if the field was Fruit, and the Contact ID is 727, then the two rows would look like
| ID | Fruit |
| 727 | Apple |
| 727 | Banana |
